# What does $\sum_{n=0}^\infty z^{n(n+1)/2}$, $|z|<1$ converge to?

Tags: sequences-and-series, power-series, theta-functions

Does anyone know what the series
$$
S(z) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} z^\frac{n(n+1)}{2}
$$
converges to for $|z|<1$? This came up in an application where $z$ is a probability and $S(z)$ an expected value. The exponent comes from the fact that $\sum_{k=0}^nk=\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$. I think $S(z)$ should definitely converge because the coefficients are nonnegative and form a subsequence of the well-known $\sum_{n=0}^\infty z^n=\frac{1}{1-z}$. Is there a closed-form representation of $S(z)$?

Comment: Really sorry for asking this, but is z complex or real?

Comment: Let's say it is complex, although a result for $z\in[0,1[$ would also be nice.

Answer (score 3):

The Wikipedia article [Ramanujan theta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramanujan_theta_function)
states

> $\psi(q) = f(q,q^3) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty q^{n(n+1)/2}
> = (q^2;q^2)_\infty(-q;q)_\infty $

and, yes, this converges only for $\,|q|<1.$
Note that his is as close to closed
form as you can get. A more complicated
expression for this is in terms of a Jacobi
theta function.

Comment: There is also an integral representation for it in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramanujan_theta_function#Integral_representations

Answer (score 3):

Using Jacobi [Elliptic theta](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/JacobiThetaFunctions.html) function
$$\vartheta _2(u,q)=2 \sqrt[4]{q} \sum _{n=0}^{\infty } q^{n(n+1)} \cos ((2 n+1) u)$$
we can conclude that
$$\sum _{n=0}^{\infty } z^{\frac{1}{2} n (n+1)}=\frac{\vartheta _2\left(0,\sqrt{z}\right)}{2 \sqrt[8]{z}}$$
To satisfy my curiosity I plotted (for real $z$ with $|z|<1$) the graph of such an "exotic" function, below.

---

[image: graph below]